# Deriving the normal force for an oscillatory system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following exercise:

> 4) Consider a U-tube filled with a liquid with density . If you blow
>   into one of the sides, the liquid in both sides is displaced from the
>   equilibrium position as shown in the figure. The  liquid then
>   oscillates back and forth. Neglect the effect of friction, so assume
>   that the oscillation is undamped. The U-tube has an area A. The total 
>   length of the liquid column is L, its volume is V.
>
> a) Derive an
>    expression for the restoring force as a function of displacement x.

[image]

Here is my thought process:

- The mass of the red section of the graphics can be expressed as $m = \rho V$
- The liquid is said to oscillate undamped. This means its net force must be of the form $F_{net} = -kx$. Otherwise it would not have this type of motion.
- Considering the red section of the liquid in a free body diagram, with $\pm \ x$ from the left and right and $\pm \ y$ up and down the screen, we note there is no net force in $x$ and consider in $y$:

$$F_{net} = n - mg$$

Where $n$ is some normal force.

Since I've found two true expressions for the net force on this red section, I arrive at:

$$ n - mg = -kx$$
$$ n = -kx + mg$$
$$n = - kx + \rho V g$$

Does this look reasonable? Am I missing anything noteworthy in my thought process?

Comment: Why not do some research on the Internet to find something like this? http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/utube_osc.pdf

Comment: @Farcher Appreciate the source - did not expect an example this specific would even have anything about this.